# Can I use ARM JSON script to apply restrictions to subscriptions on Azure Stack?

Tags: azure-rm-template, azure-stack

So I manage Azure stack and I want to put a cap on the number of Windows VMs that could be created per subscription and I also need it in template form for automation. So far I have not been able to do that. Could I please get some help?

Answer (score 0):

Such restrictions on Azure Subscriptions are usually applied by implementing [Azure Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/overview) (which can also be programmatically created and managed) but looks like it is not yet supported on Azure Stack. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/289857/azure-policy-on-azure-stack-hub.html) similar thread for details.